# Django Create View form validation warnings

Tags: django, forms, validation, view, field

I have a **Create View** form that looks like this:

```
class LineItemCreateView(CreateView):
model = LineItem
fields = ('sku', 'description', 'quantity', 'order', 'status')

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(LineItemCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['order'].initial = self.kwargs['order_id']
    form.fields['description'].widget = forms.Textarea()
    return form
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:order_id>/add-new-record/',
     LineItemCreateView.as_view(), name='lineitem_form'),
```

and **html** **template**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formnovalidate>Save record</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

When the user loads the form page for the first time, validation warnings appear for every field. This behavior is causing the form to not show initial values I have set. However, if I refresh the URL, then everything looks the way it should.

I believe validation messages should appear after user clicks submit, not before. How can I remove the validation so it doesn't show up when user first opens the form?

[Button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptOWP.png)

[First load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8izEw.png)

[Desired first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Jon.png)

Additional reference: [Disable validation when calling form for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559853/disable-validation-when-calling-form-for-the-first-time)

Comment: How is that page loaded the first time?  The fact that you see validation errors means that the form was initialised with data (and validated), which can only happen on a post request.

Comment: The page is loaded when user clicks on the button Add New Item. I have updated my question with additional images and code.

Comment: And what's the code for this button "Add new item"?

Comment: `<form action="/ocal/{{ object.id }}/add-new-record/" method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="New Item" />
  </div>
</form>`

Comment: There you are, you button is submitting a form with POST but that's not what you want, it should just be making a GET request to the url: Remove the entire form and just use `<a href="/ocal/{{object.id}}/add-new-record">New Item</a>` or better `<a href="{% url 'lineitem_form' object.id %}">New Item</a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is validated on first launch because you're fetching your view with a POST request instead of a GET request. When you POST to the view, you're submitting data for the form, even if that data is empty. So your form will be **bound** to the data, validated and contain errors.

You need to launch your view with a GET request. Make sure the link to your view is just a plain link (`<a>` tag), not a submit button.

Comment: Aha, I understand. That solved my problem. Thank you.